# UnsatisfiedLinkError while loading native library

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, 64-bit

I'm trying to use native library from my java program.
I can successfully load `libpHash.so` in `/usr/local/lib` by the following command.

```
System.loadLibrary("pHash");
```

But when I trying to load `libpHash-jni.so` in the same folder by calling `System.loadLibrary("pHash-jni")` I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /usr/local/lib/libpHash-jni.so: libpHash.so.0: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

Why?

---

Some additional information:

- `libpHash.so` and `libpHash.so.0` are both symbolic links to `libpHash.so.0.0.0`
- `libpHash.so.0.0.0` and `libpHash-jni.so` are both ELF 64-bit LSB shared object
- I have 64 bit JVM

Comment: check if another application in your container has loaded this program, in case if you are running a webapplication

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is updating the dynamic linker cache with `ldconfig`. If this doesn't solve the problem you might also try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

and restart your program.